# Which skills can reveal enemies?

Tags: league-of-legends

Leaving out Clairvoyance, wards and other items which reveal enemies like the new Wriggles in twisted treeline,

```
which champion skills grant vision through the fog of war? (e.g. in bushes?)
```

I'm not talking about stealth opponents.

For example:

Mundo's Cleaver (Q) does **not** reveal champions it hits.

Malzahar's Silence (Q) though reveals any champion it hits briefly.

Comment: I haven't played all of the champions, but their are a few that I play on a regular basis that have an ability which will give vision in brush even for just a split second. Anivia's Wall(W) and Caitlyn's Trap(also W) both will give vision for any brush they are thrown into. Anivia's Wall grants vision the entire duration it is up, where as Caitlyn's trap will only provide vision for a split second, but can confirm or deny the presence of enemies in that bush in front of you, not to mention if they step on the trap I get vision on them and anyone around them for a brief time.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind are skill shots which are making a specific noise when they hit something. It won't reveal the enemy, but it will tell you if one is there.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer I'm not sure about your edit. I know you have tried to make the question more global and accessible to others, but isn't clearing the fog and checking bushes a different thing? Even though (almost?) all skills that clear fog of war also clear bushes.

Comment: @Joetjah Yeah I m not sure about that either. Although I don't really mind it. Plus I really like the title change so thx Raven ;)

Comment: It gives room for more options in the answer. It includes the clearing of bushes. It did change the question though. People browsing for the same question you originally had won't find this so fast I think. Even so, I admit I do like the new title more, haha.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taken from: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Brush.

Skills that give visual of the brush:

> - Ashe's Enchanted Arrow reveals the Area it passes over.
> - Ashe's  Hawkshot will reveal the area it passes over and within its
>     explosion radius.
> - Cassiopeia's  Miasma grants vision where it is
>     cast for its duration.
> - Evelynn's  Agony's Embrace will grant vision
>     for an instant when it lands in the brush.
> - Ezreal's Trueshot Barrage reveals the Area it passes over.
> - Jarvan IV's  Demacian Standard will reveal a small sized area on the point of impact.
> - Leona's Solar Flare reveals an area around the target location.
> - Lux's  Lucent Singularity grants vision where it is cast until it is
>     detonated.
> - Lux's Final Spark will grant vision directly before and after firing
> - Malzahar's  Call of the Void grants vision along the
>     tips of the spell during casting animation.
> - Maokai's  Sapling Toss
>     will give sight of the targeted area during flight and on landing.
> - Miss Fortune's  Make It Rain will grant sight within the affected area
>     for its duration.
> - Olaf's  Undertow will grant vision for an instant
>     when it lands in the brush.
> - Urgot's  Noxian Corrosive Charge will
>     reveal a medium sized area on the point of impact.
> - Teemo's  Noxious Trap will give sight around it, however the radius of vision is very
>     small.
> - Thresh's Dark Passage reveals an area around the lantern.
> - Heimerdinger's  H-28G Evolution Turret will reveal the whole
>     brush as if a minion walked into it
> - Corki's  Phosphorous Bomb will
>     reveal brush if it is within its detonation range.
> - Karthus's  Wall
>     of Pain will grant a small area of vision for any section of brush it
>     passes through.
> - Karthus's  Lay Waste will also grant a small area
>     of vision, but requires multiple Lay Wastes in different locations.
> - Yorick's  Omen of Pestilence will reveal brush where minion is.
> - Zed's Living Shadow reveals an area around the shadow's location.
> - Ziggs's  Satchel Charge will grant vision where it is cast for its
>     duration.
> - Zyra's Rampant Growth gives vision of the brush for a short duration when the seed is placed inside the brush.
> - Heimerdinger's CH-1 Concussion Grenade gives vision of the brush when the grenade is thrown in the bush.
> - Nidalee's Bushwhack gives vision of the brush for a short duration when the trap is placed inside the brush.

Reveal enemies that touch or aggro them within the brush

> - Anivia's  Crystallize
> - Corki's  Phosphorous Bomb
> - Heimerdinger's  H-28G Evolution Turret
> - Karthus's  Wall of Pain
> - Shaco's  Jack In The Box
> - Syndra's Scatter The Weak will reveal enemies if one of her spheres hit an enemy.
> - Teemo's  Noxious Trap
> - Trundle's  Pillar of Filth
> - Ziggs's  Hexplosive Minefield
> - Lee Sin's Sonic Wave/Resonating Strike and Tempest/Cripple will reveal any enemy (including invisible) as long as they are affected.

Skill that give vision of the brush differently:

> - Twisted Fate's  Destiny will reveal all enemy champions even if they are in brush.
> - Warwick's  Blood Scent will reveal nearby enemy champions who are below half health even if they are in brush (only applicable within radius of effect and will not reveal stealthed champions, however he will receive the speed boost, thus detecting them).
> - Elise's Rappel gives vision of all units in a range.

There are champions who can summon pets. These pets can either spawn in a brush or need to be sent there first. They also give vision if they walk into a bush:

> - Annie's Summon Tibbers
> - Elise's Spider Swarm
> - Malzahar's Summon Voidling
> - Mordekaiser's Children of the Grave
> - Shaco's Hallucinate
> - Yorick's Omen of Pestilence (Only when cast inside the bush. This ghosts is not controllable and will not follow the enemies inside a bush when that bush covers their presence)
> - Yorick's Omen of Death

If a player fires a skill shot into the brush, it won't make them visible even if you hit them. However many of them have a secondary effect or a different sound effect on impact:

> - Ahri's  Orb of Deception and  Charm will add stacks to her passive if they hit.
> - Ashe's  Volley arrows will disappear and not travel their full distance if they hit anything.
> - Brand's  Sear disappears before its full distance is travelled if it hits something.
> - Caitlyn's  Piltover Peacemaker makes a distinctive sound if it hits.
> - Cassiopeia's  Noxious Blast gives her a buff if it hits
> - Dr. Mundo's  Infected Cleaver makes a splattering sound if it hits, and heals  Dr. Mundo.
> - Ezreal's  Mystic Shot makes a distinctive sound if it hits, reduces other cooldowns if it hits and will apply one stack of his innate ability  Rising Spell Force.
> - Karma's  Heavenly Wave makes a distinctive sound if it hits.
> - Kennen's  Thundering Shuriken makes a distinctive sound if it hits. The target will also gain a  Mark of the Storm which will enable the use of  Electrical Surge if you are close enough.
> - Lulu's Glitterlance makes a distinctive sounds if it hits.
> - Mordekaiser's  Siphon of Destruction makes a distinctive sound if it hits, and increases his  Iron Man.
> - Morgana's  Dark Binding makes a distinctive sound if it hits.
> - Nidalee's  Javelin Toss makes a distinctive sound if it hits.
> - Nocturne's  Duskbringer makes a distinctive sound if it hits, as well as causing a trail to appear.
> - Rumble's  Electro-Harpoon makes a distinctive sound if it hits.
> - Shyvana's  Flame Breath makes a distinctive sound if it hits.
> - Sivir's  Boomerang Blade makes a distinctive sound if it hits.
> - Talon's  Rake makes a distinctive sound if it hits.
> - Thresh's Death Sentence makes a distinctive sound if it hits. The skill also allows to be recast with a different icon on hit.
> - Varus's  Piercing Arrow makes a distinctive sound if it hits.
> - Morgana's  Tormented Soil will apply spell vamp if a target is in brush due to her innate ability  Soul Siphon.
> - Lux's Light Binding will not travel any further after hitting two(!) targets, but pass through the first
> - Any skill shot which does not apply on-hit effects (like lifesteal) will trigger spell vamp if it hits a target in Brush.

Comment: Nidalee's trap will also grant vision for an instant, even though this is not restricted to bushes

Comment: I can't elaborate on that, I'm not a Nidalee player at all (my spears will miss even if I'm close). I do remember some skills/traps (maybe it is Nidalee's after all) which lightens up the area, clearing it from Fog, but NOT granting vision. It seemed like the bush was empty but when I walked in, I encountered an enemy. I have encountered before but I'm unsure which champion that was. I can playtest Nid's behaviour in an hour or two and I'll update my answer if proven right.

Comment: In short: I believe there was a skill that made it seem like you checked the bush, but it only removed Fog. It didn't show the bushes contect, though.

Comment: Still didnt add Caitlyn's trap

Comment: Down voted as incomplete list

Comment: Heimerdinger's Grenade also reveals Brush if you throw it inside.

Comment: It's indeed an incomplete list, I found 2 more. I'll update the list according to comments and own findings. Feel free to edit my answer as well!

Comment: Missing: Lulu's Q (Glitterlance) makes a distinctive sound if you hit. Thresh's Q (Death Sentence) makes a distinctive sound on hit, and also allows it to be recast with a different icon. Leona's R (Solar Flare) reveals an area around the target location. Thresh's W (Dark Passage) reveals an area around the lantern. Zed's W (Living Shadow) reveals an area around it. Hitting an enemy with one of Syndra's Dark Spheres by casting her E (Scatter the Weak) will reveal it. Anything that summons a pet (Elise's transform, Annie's R) will reveal. [There are lots more, but I can't think of any for now.]

Comment: I've added them all, keep the suggestions coming!

Comment: Remember people that you can edit an answer to improve it with what is missing, instead of downvoting.

Comment: For people adding (and reading), note that the lists are sorted alphabetically. A few things are out of line but I'm waiting for the next edit to fix that. If people want to edit themselves, please place it in the correct position.

Comment: @Yves I don't think Annie's bear counts, because you can control it to move where you want like a champion. Ofcourse it is going to give you vision then... Just like Shaco's clone and mordekaisers ghost...

Comment: But when I play Annie and are in a teamfight, which I survive and I head into the jungle, I often use the still alive Tibbers to stand a distance away from me so I can jungle while Tibbers provides a vision of a certain area. It's a skill and it grants vision, so I think it counts. I'm going to add Shaco and Mordekaiser to the list, though!

Comment: I also made a list especially for the pet-types. That would make it more clear.